# Excel VBA Range Calculation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm working on creating a monthly consolidation function which doesn't like how I'm using this particular snippet of my code:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets

 If Len(ws.Name) <= 5 Then
    ws.Range("B7:C7").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B7:C100"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B7:C100").Select

 End If

 Next
```

All client profiles are filled out via a template which self duplicates for each new individual so the profiles are all standardised. All user profiles are <=5 characters (acronyms). So the intent of my code is to check if the tab is <=5 characters, and then if it is - select the first range B7:C7 and clear this. Next we apply this cleared filter to all the other cells as well (down to 100).

I've defined ws as my Worksheet variable and I don't understand why I can't set the ws.range as B7:C7. I'd appreciate your insight!

I've attached a snapshot of what the form looks like.[image: Snapshot of tool]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If Len(ws.Name) <= 5 Then ws.Range("B7:C100").ClearContents
Next
```

Notes:

- the .Select statement requires ws to be activated
- you don't need to use .Select in this case (you can act on the range directly)
- the .AutoFill is not bad but here is not needed

  - its usefulness is when incrementing initial data

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for that Paul! I'm still getting used to VBA. These tips are helpful!